# Remove lockscreen in android kiosk mode

Tags: android, api

All the past answers to this question seem to be redundant.

I've managed to successfully load a test device with android kiosk mode, which runs a single use app upon booting up and it stays there full screen the whole time the device is on however because the device is in an inclosed cabinet for the public it should not need any user intervention when booting up. currently after booting up it shows the lockscreen (no password). a person must swipe UP before the kiosk mode is revealed with the single use app running. its very important to find a way to completely remove the lockscreen so the device just boots up without any user intervention and continues performing its task as per normal.

your feedback will be greatly appreciated!
thanks
siz